# Macbook pro boot with kernel panic - can't perform kext scan

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, startup, kernel-panic

I was trying to swap command and option key for my external keyboard following the instruction in 
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110529094802391.

When I'm done with change and I restarted, my mac booted with Kernel panic message. I'm sure I've messed the info.plist file. Now I cannot boot in safe mode as well.

I know if I get a way to change the file it should be fine.

The message shown in screen is

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80002c4794): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80005eae1e, type 14=page fault, registers: ...
Debugger called: <panic>
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Addressd
...
...
can't perform kext scan: no kext summary
BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Unknown

Mac OS version:
Not yet set

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48PM
Kernel UUID: ...
System uptime in nanoseconds: 11...
```

The error specifies the problem in kext as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest thing to do is boot into [OS X Recovery](http://www.apple.com/osx/recovery/) and re-install the OS.

You could alternatively boot into Recovery and open terminal and hope to fix the format of the kext file on disk, but I'd say it would be safer to start that Mac in target mode and copy in an unmodified copy of IOHIDFamily.kext into /System/Library/Extensions

Unless you have a good backup of the Mac, it's safer to just reinstall the core OS which will leave your user files and accounts alone, but remedy this system file that is needed for the system to run.

Comment: I did backup of IOHIDFamily.kext file. I had a bootable cd of mac osx which came with the mac. I was able to boot from cd and replace the modified file with backup one.

I'm able to boot normally now.

Comment: @darkapple Awesome! good thinking with the backup and knowing how to swap it back in. Now that you can get a good backup, you can boot to recovery, use terminal and try to edit the file - knowing you can go back to terminal and fix it next time.

Comment: Hey I'm having the same error on sierra OS. It's installed into a SSD. Sometimes this even power up and the apple at the startup doesn't show. Do you think this can be solve by reinstalling th os?

Comment: It couldn't hurt to reinstall @BraianMellor. Feel free to report your specific panic message and link here - I'll have a look if reinstall doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Look at this https://ibb.co/h0dyAa

Answer (score -3):

Switch off S.M.A.R.T. in your bios settings

Comment: What BIOS settings are you referring to on Apple hardware?